# What is the difference between explicitly writing public and not writing public?

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I thought there was no difference but then I encountered this:

```
public class Whatever
{

 String toString()  
{
//stuff
}

}
```

This code results in the compiler error:

> `toString()` in `Whatever` cannot override `toString()` in `java.lang.Object`; attempting to assign weaker access privileges; was `public`

If I explicitly type `public String toString()` the code compiles just fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't use the `public` access specifier for methods and fields, they are assumed to be under `package`-level visibility.

Here is a nice diagram of what `package` and `public` mean in terms of visibility outside of your class:

```
Modifier       Class    Package   Subclass  World
----------------------------------------------------------
public           Y         Y         Y        Y       
protected        Y         Y         Y        N
no modifier      Y         Y         N        N       <--- This is package level
private          Y         N         N        N
```

`Y` means that the method, class, or field is visible.

`N` means that the method, class, or field is *not* visible

Comment: `package` isn't an actual keyword in Java is it?

Comment: @millimoose the `package` keyword is used to denote that a class X is in a package Y. As for access control, no the keyword package isn't used.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by your last statement.  
What do you mean package isn't used for access control?

Comment: @KacyRaye The keyword `package` itself isn't used. Meaning that if you write a function that you want to have `pacakage` visibility you dont say `package void myMethod(....)` you just leave off the specifier entirely `void myMethod(....)`

Comment: Oh never mind I know what you mean now. 
I wouldn't explicitly type the keyword package when creating the method like I would with keywords public and private.
Thank you. Your explanation was clear. I'll accept the answer as soon as it lets me(3 minutes).

Answer (score 0):

@Hunter McMillen mentioned the package level visibility (+1).

I just want to add a brief explanation what does it mean. It means that classes from the same package and sub classes of current class even if they themselves belong to other package can access this method/field.

Answer (score 0):

In inheritance, when overriding methods you cannot narrow down access scope of a method. Here, the `toString()` method from `Object` class has `public` access and your class `Whatever` is trying to narrow down it's scope by changing access level to `package` (equivalent to no access modifier is specified) and this is not allowed.

A `package` level method can be defined as

```
void someMethod () {
}
```

If you see here, there is no access modifier before `void`, i.e. `public`, `protected` or `private` which implies all classes that are in the same package as `Whatever` will be able to access it. Any package outside of the package will not be able to access this method, not even a subclass of `Whatever`.

When you explicitly write `public`, entire would can use it at will.

Comment: When you say subclass, you're referring to extensions of classes right?
So let's say I have:
public class Whatever{ 
//method with package visibility
}

Then another class file:
public class Hello extends Whatever {}

The class Hello would not have access to methods in Whatever with package visibility?

Comment: Only when class `Hello` is in some other package. If class `Whatever` and `Hello` are in same package, `Hello` will have access to the methods with package visibility.